# Chrome Devtools Protocol - What does the scale parameter do in the clip argument?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to take the screenshot of an element selected by the user. To take the screenshot, I get the `ClientBoundingRect` for the element, add scrollX and scrollY to the x and y locations of the `ClientBoundingRect` and then set the `x`, `y`, `height`, `width` of the `clip` argument to the `Page.captureScreenshot`. There is another parameter to the `clip` argument called `scale`. I do not understand what the parameter does. Here are my observations:

1. If the set `scale` to 0, then the screenshot that gets captured is empty.
2. If I set the `scale` to 1, then the screenshot is non empty, is of the right size, but it captures the wrong part of the screen. I also notice that when the screenshot is being taken, the viewport size reduces to the height and width specified in `clip` parameter.

My questions are as follows:

1. What does the `scale` parameter do?
2. What would be the right way of capturing the screenshot of an element, selected by the user.

Thanks.

[1]https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot
[2]https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#type-Viewport

Comment: I also noticed that the `clip` argument requires all the parameters in `Device Independent Pixels` instead of `Pixels`. Is there a conversion required?

Comment: See the logic in the source code ([frontend](https://crsrc.org/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/panels/emulation/DeviceModeWrapper.ts;l=150-159) and [backend](https://crsrc.org/content/browser/devtools/protocol/page_handler.cc?q=symbol:PageHandler::CaptureScreenshot)). See also how to spy on devtools' own usage of these commands via Protocol Monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Referred the frontend code and modified mine accordingly. Works as expected now.